# Cannot use GridLayout in Android studio

Tags: android, layout, grid, box

as I understand Grid Layout is part of Legacy code? anyways, I downloaded it and when I try to apply it, it gives me this Gray box and I cannot seem to use it all, any solutions? what can i use instead of GridLayout? I am making tic tac toe game and i need to divide the screen 3 by 3, any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: What does the red exclamation tell you?

Comment: nothing changes by adding constraints, im asking how to get rid of the gray box and have the box white instead. I can change the width and height of the box but i cannot set the background etc

Answer (score 0):

using recycLerView with gridLayoutManager has verry better performance.

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```